# Ruby on rails execute show instead index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a resource called centers defined in routes.rb. When I get localhost:3000/centers centers_controller execute show action instead index. That should not happen according to Ruby on Rails CRUD documentation.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try to look into log file as well as try to debug ?
What's actually the log saying ?

Comment: provide rake:routes output

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While someone may get lucky trying to answer this, most of us will need more information like the output of `rake routes`, and your routes.rb file.

Answer (score 7):

I have one point. Are you using

```
   resource :centers
```

or

```
   resources :centers
```

2nd option has index action, first one not

Comment: resource :center then